# How to write a two-pass system in TeX?

Tags: tex-core

On page 400 of *The TeXbook* ("Dirty tricks" part) it is said:

> An output routine can also write notes on a file, based on what occurs in a manuscript. A two-pass system can be devised where TeX simply gathers information during the first pass; the actual typesetting can be done during the second pass, using `\read` to recover information that was written during the first.

What might be the simplest example of such a two-pass system which solves the following problem from exercise 14.28 of *TeXbook*?

> ... because the depth of the line depends on details of line breaking that aren't known until afterwards.

The following may be used as a template:

```
\def\marginalstar{\vadjust{\kern-R\smash{\llap{* }}\kernR}}
\nopagenumbers
\hsize0.8in
\noindent
Quick brown fox eats a
\marginalstar
big fat
mouse.
\bye
```

where **R** is to be calculated during the first pass and used in the second.

Comment: Why is there a close vote on this? Especially after 4 minutes?

Comment: by far the most commonly used implementation of such a system is the latex .aux file which is written on one pass and read on the next for tables of contents and cross referencing information but also widths of table columns, and anything else.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How to do it without extra layers, using only core of TeX?

Comment: the latex source code is readable, and a good source of examples for many of the kinds of things you ask about. Of course latex isn't really an "extra layer" it is the same number of layers as plain tex, just that a more functional set of macros is loaded into the format.  I may however post some plain code later if no one has answered, no time now:-)

Comment: This should not be closed. Please wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Also, if you downvote, please don't forget to revert the vote after the question is improved.

Comment: Just for the record, here are some links which  address this problem: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-2/tb98hicks.pdf, lineno package, http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99isambert.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\pfdsavepos` for measuring the depth of the previous line while using `\vadjust`. But this is not classical TeX, this is from pdfTeX extension:

```
This is the line in the paragraph%
\pdfsavepos\write16{\the\pdflastypos}%
\vadjust{\pdfsavepos\write16{\the\pdflastypos}}
this continues the line in the paragraph,
this continues the line in the paragraph.
```

You can write the result to the output file (replace 16 by something more appropriate) and you can read this file again in the next step. The information in the file (from this example) is in the form:

```
49989344
49861913
```

This means that the depth of the measured line is `49989344-49861913 = 127431 sp`. This is approximately 1.944pt.

**Edit** Because the name of the thread, I show a full implementation of this feature:

```
\newcount\marnum   \newcount\tmpnum
\newwrite\marfile  \newread\testin

\def\marX#1#2{\advance\marnum by1 \tmpnum=#1 \advance\tmpnum by-#2
   \expandafter \edef \csname mar:\the\marnum\endcsname{\the\tmpnum}}

\openin\testin=\jobname.mar
\ifeof\testin \message{Warning: file \jobname.mar does not exist, TeX me again}%
\else \closein\testin \input \jobname.mar \fi

\immediate\openout\marfile=\jobname.mar
\marnum=0

\def\marginalnote#1{\global\advance\marnum by1
  \expandafter\ifx\csname mar:\the\marnum\endcsname \relax
     \def\kernR{0pt}\else\edef\kernR{\csname mar:\the\marnum\endcsname sp}\fi
  \pdfsavepos\write\marfile{\string\marX{\the\pdflastypos}}%
  \vadjust{\pdfsavepos\write\marfile{{\the\pdflastypos}}%
     \kern-\kernR\smash{\llap{#1 }}\kern\kernR}}

This is the line in the paragraph%
\marginalnote{XX}
this continues the line in the paragraph,
this continues the line in the paragraph.

Second m. note:\marginalnote{YY}

\end
```

All marginal notes have unique number in the document `\marnum`. If the temporary file `\jobname.mar` exists then it is read using `\input` and the information is saved using `\marX` to the macro `\mar:mar-num`. The `\marginalnote` reads this information if exists else it uses `R=0pt`.

Comment: Your solution is good. Is it possible to do it using only TeX?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko No. `\pdfsavepos` in pdfTeX primitive.

Comment: Is it possible to add `\par\showboxdepth0\showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showlists` to the paragraph which has \vadjust during the first pass and see depth **R** of the hbox just before `\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0 []` in the trace file? Or maybe there is a e-TeX solution? Maybe there is a trick in the output routine which will let to do it without creating an auxiliary file at all? And also is it possible to print "TeX me again" also when the data in `.mar` file is not up-to-date (not only when `.mar` file does not exist)?

Comment: I just wanted to ask for an advice: Is it possible, in principle, to do marginal notes via `\insert`? Is it feasible to split marginal notes across a page automatically (like footnotes)? Or fully-functional marginal notes are impossible in TeX (e-TeX)?

Comment: I have an idea how to do it using only TeX, but I do not know how to implement it. Is it possible to do this: we need to know the depth of the line on the first pass, thus we just care about line breaks, not pagebreaks. So on the first pass we call \eject in \vadjust and use special penalty value which carries the number of margin note. Then in special output routine we see \dp255 and record it in file, and on the second pass we read this depth (similar to this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201104/is-there-a-way-to-get-at-the-value-of-prevdepth-from-the-main-vertical-list-ins)